# Right-continuous for every decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

Let $f \colon I \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ a function. I want to show that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for every sequence $(x_n)$ with $x\leq x_n$ and $x_n \to x$ iff $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for every strictly decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ with $x\leq x_n$ and $x_n \to x$. But I don't know how i can do this. Can I maybe use the sequence $a_k= \sup_{n \geq k} x_n$?

Comment: Do you mean $(x_k)$ convergent? Otherwise $(x_n)$ could alternate infinitely between two fixed values $y,z \geq x$, and we will not have convergence of $f(x_n)$.

Comment: Yes, i mean $x_n \to x$ (Sorry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One direction ($\implies$) of the equivalence is trivial. For the other direction ($\impliedby$) assume that $(x_n)$ is a sequence with $x_n \ge x$, $x_n \to x$, but $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ does not hold. Then you can extract a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $(f(x_{n_k}))$ is convergent, with $f(x_{n_k}) \to c \ne f(x)$. Note that $x_{n_k} > x$ must hold for all but finitely many $k$. Finally extract a strictly decreasing subsequence $(x_{n_{k_j}})$ to get a contradiction.

This is an example of the following principle:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence with the property that every subsequence of $(a_n)$ has a subsequence that converges to $A$. Then $(a_n)$ converges to $A$.